# Simple Question on Maximizing Point on linear two-variable function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$. How would I maximize $f(x, y) := \frac{1}{4}x + \frac{1}{3}y$ given that $x + y = N$ and $x, y \geq 0$ ? I've looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519192/maximize-two-variable-linear-function), but the second link in the answer doesn't work! The KKT conditions that the answerer references are for non-linear systems, so I'm not sure how that even helps the OP of that post. Anyway, all that I've tried so far, sadly, is substitution and GeoGebra... Thanks.

Comment: What are you studying right now, or how this question comes up?

Comment: Also, the KKT conditions can also be applied to linear systems.

Comment: @Tab1e I have a dimension formula for certain spaces I'm interested in. I'm trying to make a bound on that formula for those spaces of a special type. This question may or may not help me with that.

Comment: In your case, check the branch and bound method in integer programming.

Comment: @Tab1e Interesting. I'll read up on that, thanks.

Comment: Simply, use the constraint to remove one variable and solve the resulting univariate problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exploit a simple property of linear problems. The solution is one of the intersections of the constraints.

These intersections are $(0,0)$, $(0,N)$ and $(N,0)$.

The one that maximizes $f$ and satisfies $x+y=N$ is $(0,N)$. Thus the solution is $(0,N)$.

Comment: Yes, I realized this simple solution and forgot to post. Thank you for taking the time :-)